# Window Azure Active Directory - Service Provide Initiated

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, azure-active-directory

I am creating 2 websites:

1. http://training.xyz.com
2. http://portal.xyz.com

I would like to use Window Azure Active Directory for single sign on (Service Provider Initiated)

I created 2 apps in the Windows Azure Active Directory. But after I login to http://training.xyz.com and then visit http://portal.xyz.com I am prompted to login again at http://portal.xyz.com, should I not just be logged in? Am I missing something that someone can point out to me? Does Windows Azure Active Directory not support Service Provider Initiated single sign on?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD does support SP initiated SSO. The behavior you should see is a prompt less sign-in on the second app. If you aren't, please check a couple things: 1) cookies are enabled and 2) the second website is indeed issuing a sign on request to AAD on the home page (http://portal.xyz.com/) - this request will result in a silent redirect response.

Hope this helps.